# Screen Flow Error on an External Web Application

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework, salesforce-flow

I am embedding a Salesforce screen flow in my web application using Lighting Out feature. It worked for very basic screen flow with 2 screens but when I used a complex screen flow it is showing me following error:

**Screen Flow Error:**
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during LWC component connect phase: [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getReference')]] Failing descriptor: {markup://flowruntime:auraField}

I am facing above error while running web application, I can see the flow button but fields are not showing because of above error.

**-- Aura Component --**

```js
<!-- auraScreenFlow.cmp -->

<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowScreen" />
</aura:component>

<!-- auraScreenFlowController.js -->

({
    init : function(component) {
        var flow = component.find("flowScreen");
        flow.startFlow("flow_api_name");
    }
})
```

**-- Lightning Application --**

```html
<!-- auraScreenFlowApplication.app -->

<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:auraScreenFlow" />
</aura:application>
```

**-- Web Application HTML --**

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<div id="flow"></div>

<script src="https://myorg.lightning.force.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<script>
    $Lightning.use('c:auraScreenFlowApplication',
            function () {
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    'c:auraScreenFlow',
                    {},
                    "flow",
                    function (cmp) {
                        console.log('Created', { cmp });
                    }
                );
            },
            'https://myorg.lightning.force.com/',
            'access-token'
        );
</script>
```

I configured Lightning Out feature properly. Created a Connected App, Saved `https://localhost:8081` in CORS setting of my Org, and my web app is running fine. But after loading of Lightning App, Screen Flow only shows button not fields that are in flow.

**I searched for solution applied some solutions and still facing same issue.**

Please, tell me why I'm facing this problem and How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not post images or links to images of code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5031762 for explanation.

Comment: Replaced code snippet images with code snippet.